# How to parse a collection of lists returned from cypher?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Using python/py2neo, I run a cypher query containing

```
return ..., ...,  collect([node1.uuid, node1.timestamp, id(node1), node2.uuid])
```

Both in web console and py2neo I get back a result looking like this:

```
[ ..., ..., [u'List(1234abcd-1234-1234-1234-1234abcd1234, 1.374650647E9, 13312, 4321abcd-4321-4321-4321-4321abcd4321)', u'List(..., ..., ...)']]
```

(just with `""` instead of `u''` in web console)

It doesn't look like JSON. There's a `u'List()'`, unquoted strings and scientific notation.

How is it possible to parse returned collections of lists?

Comment: version of neo? I'm pretty sure this was fixed in late 1.9 milestones and 2.0.

Comment: great, then there's hope! stuck with the hosted 1.8.1 for the time being..

Comment: It might even be in 1.8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with regex:

```
import re
s = u'List(1234abcd-1234-1234-1234-1234abcd1234, 1.374650647E9, 13312, 4321abcd-4321-4321-4321-4321abcd4321)'
re.findall(r'List\(([a-z0-9-]+), ([0-9.E]+), (\d+), ([a-z0-9-]+)\)', s)
```

this would return:

```
[(u'1234abcd-1234-1234-1234-1234abcd1234',
  u'1.374650647E9',
  u'13312',
  u'4321abcd-4321-4321-4321-4321abcd4321')]
```

Comment: I'll accept this if there's not a more semantic answer - for now, thanks for saving my day ;)

Comment: essentially, tweaking the cypher output such that it returns a real serialization of variables as it usually does. Also I'm calling this query through an ORM with automatic object inflation - which won't work if I can only tweak the data afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the actual REST calls (switch to the HTTP console view or use CURL), you can do in the HTTP Webadmin Console something like

```
POST /db/data/cypher {"query":"start n=node(1,2) return collect(n);"}
```

And will get correct serialized full node red=representations in a [] back.

Comment: Based on Wes comment I'll go with pattern matching until heroku sees an update. Btw, it works for collect() of nodes, just fails for collect(array of node info).